# Dynamically generated form choices in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form for submitting new articles in Django, in this form you're allowed to place the post into a 'user_group', just a many many relationship between groups and users.  However, you're only allowed to add it into groups you belong to.  Using the init function of the form class i can pass in an extra field, and I do get the correct choices I need, however on submit I get an error ''QueryDict' object has no attribute 'all''

I'm not sure whats going wrong, heres my form:

```
class PostForm(BaseModelForm):
new_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
#GROUPS = user.groups.all()
#group = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GROUPS, required=False )

def __init__(self,groups, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['group'].queryset = groups

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','category', 'group', 'text', 'description', 'style')

        help_texts = {
            'group': _('Do you want this published under your account or a group?')
        }
```

and heres the view where the error is being thrown:

```
@login_required
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(groups=request.user.user_groups.all())
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

This line:

```
form = PostForm(groups=request.user.user_groups.all())
```

Is where I pass in the choices for groups, which does give you the correct choices.  The fact that the error happens on submitting make me think its an error in how the view processes it, but Im not sure where.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Specifically, it is not clear whether `class Meta` is supposed to be nested inside `class PostForm` or not.

Comment: Your model form should inherit `models.ModelForm`, not `BaseModelForm`.

Comment: BaseModelForm is an extension I'm using to add bootstrap classes to forms

Comment: That's a confusing name to use, since Django has a [`BaseModelForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/216bb2e8fbc3cb37615bbd70edaa73287acdca81/django/forms/models.py#L270) which you shouldn't be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `groups` to the form for `GET` and `POST` requests. At the moment you're only doing it for GET requests. It should be

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.user.user_groups.all(), request.POST, request.FILES)
    ...
```

Comment: I think this did the trick, in combination with other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to query for the groups in the form:

```
class PostForm(models.ModelForm):
    group = forms.ChoiceField(queryset = None)

    def __init__(self,groups, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'].queryset = request.user.user_groups.all()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

It's important to define queryset as None, and in `__init__` make the query when the form instance is created.

Comment: Trying this solutiong I still get the same queryset error as before